# How to consume spring StreamingResponseBody in Angular 8

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot, streaming

I have the following code in my springboot backend

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> stream() {
        File file = new File("C:\\test\\test.mp3");
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            StreamingResponseBody resp = outputStream -> {
                 IOUtils.copy(is, outputStream);
            };
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .body(resp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(null);

    }
```

I am trying to consume it in my angular app like this

**HTML**

`<p>{{ content }}</p>`

**Typescript**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/stream', {headers: header}).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.content = JSON.stringify(res);
      },
      (err: any) => {
        this.content = JSON.stringify(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

However unless I specify `responseType: 'text'` for the get method, I get only error. Also, I tried specifying responseType as blob and arraybuffer and specified several combinations of `observe: body|response|events`. Only `{}` is shown on the page. Not sure what is wrong here.

I tried following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366704/angular-doesnt-download-a-file-from-a-stream-streamingresponsebody) but not of much use.
Can some one  please throw some light on it? Thanks in advance.